# Isomorphism Between Cyclic group algebra and Quotient Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $F$ be a field. I'd like to show that:

> $a)$ If $V$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then $$F[V] \cong F[x]/(x^n - 1).$$
> $b)$ If $\operatorname{char}(F)\neq 2$, $V=\{1, f, g, fg\}$ is the Klein group, and $\phi : F[x,y] \to F[V]$ is a morphism such that $\phi(x)=1+f$ and $\phi(y)=1+g$; then
> $$F[V] \cong F[x,y]/(x^2,y^2).$$

My attempt : for $a)$ if $\varepsilon:F[x]\to F[V]$ is a morphism, then $\ker(\varepsilon)$ is an ideal of $F[x]$. Since $F[x]$ is a PID, then there exists $m \in F[x]$ monic such that $\ker(\varepsilon)=(m)$. For $b)$ I think that the kernel of of $\phi$ is $(x^2,y^2)$: we have $\phi(x^2)=\phi(y^2)=0$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want to make use of the First Isomorphism Theorem of rings here, which says that if $\varphi : R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism then $^{R}/_{\text{ker}(\varphi)} \cong S $.

You are right to consider a ring homomorphism $\varepsilon$, what is the most natural thing $\varepsilon$ can map $x$ to? how can you use this to find the kernel of $\varepsilon$?